# Filter a list of objects using a property that is another list. Using linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I've a nice situation, I think at beginning this a usual query but I'm having some problem trying to solve this, the situation is:

I've a list of "Houses", and each house have a list of "Windows". And I want to filter for a catalog only the Houses witch have a Blue windows, so my extension method of House is something like:

```
public static List<House> FilterByWindow (this IEnumerable<House> houses, Window blueOne){

    var list = houses.Select(p=>p.Windows.Where(q=>q.Color == blueOne.Color));
    return list.ToList();
}
```

Is this correct or I'm losing something? Some better suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search for `House` instances containing blue `Windows`, then use the existing `Any` extension:

```
var blueWindowHouses =
    from h in houses
    where h.Windows.Any(w => w.Color == blueOne.Color)
    select h;
```

What you have right now is *not* correct.  The `Select` extension does not filter - it is a projection, and you aren't assigning the result to anything, so that line you have is effectively a no-op.

Also, by wrapping this logic in a method, you can prevent the expression compiler from being able to translate it into a SQL statement.  Instead, write it all in one shot, as I have above, or accept and return an `IQueryable<House>` instead of accepting an `IEnumerable<House>` and returning a `List<House>`.

Comment: this solution works just fine, but now I realized that I've another business require. My final list must have just the blue windows, have some simple linq solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

```
return houses.Where(house => house.Windows.Any(window => window.Color == blue))
             .ToList();
```

Comment: That will return a `List<bool>`

Comment: `Select` and `Where` are right next to each other on my keyboard. I always mix them up.

Comment: You have dedicated keys for `Select` and `Where`?  Where can I get one of these keyboards?